# Pull image URL with $_POST

Tags: php

Trying to send an email out with an array of images... right now it just sends out an email with the "filename", but I want to pull images. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried it 2 ways:

```
$email_body .= "<img src="http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png" style="width: 30px;">&nbsp;\n";
```

and alternating quotes:

```
$email_body .= '<img src="http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png" style="width: 30px; padding: 3px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;\n';
```

It seems like something simple, but I can't figure it out. Right now it send out the "filenames" fine, with this:

```
$email_body .= "".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] ."&nbsp;\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the following ~ you do not close the `$_POST['game']` and have one too many square brackets at the end and there is a mismatch in the quote marks:

```
$email_body .= "<img src="http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png" style="width: 30px;">&nbsp;\n";
```

Should perhaps be:

```
$email_body .= "<img src='http://example.com/logos/" . $_POST["game{$result['gameID']}"] . ".png' style='width: 30px;'>&nbsp;\n";
```

Comment: That doesn't fully work, it pulls the ID instead of the filename... that is why I have it like `.$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .`

Comment: yep, I see now that the second one was `$result`, not `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$email_body ="";
$email_body .= "<img src='"."http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png' style='width: 30px;'>&nbsp";
```

You messed up with quotes

Comment: What about `<img src="`?

Comment: When I try to edit it shows me complete string but when I post it, it is getting messed. Weired.... Anyways correct ans is $email_body .= "<img src='"."http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png' style='width: 30px;'>&nbsp";

Comment: I'm not sure what this is that you are answering: `$email_body .= "<img src='"."example.com/logos/".$_POST['game';`... that doesn't make sense. There's a semicolon in there after game, and I really don't understand `src='"."`. Anyways, I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the right way: I did mess up the quotes, but your answer is still wrong.
`$email_body .= "<img src='http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png' style='width: 30px;'>&nbsp;\n";`

Comment: No... it's still wrong. It's ok I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Had quotes wrong: Correct answer is:

```
$email_body .= "<img src='http://example.com/logos/".$_POST['game' . $result['gameID']] .".png' style='width: 30px;'>&nbsp;\n";
```